# SSH cannot login from a specific user

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I am trying to connect from **userA1@hostA** to host **userB1@hostB** using ssh.

I added the content of .ssh/id_rsa.pub file from userA1 to .ssh/authorized_keys file of userB1.

Set authorized_keys and .ssh folder permission of **userB1** to 600 and 700.

Tried to login using ssh command. Got - Permission denied (publickey).

Ok, then I created a new user at **hostB**, lets call him **userB2**. Did the same things as **userB1**. And successfully login from userA1@hostA to userB2@hostB!

So, I am totally confused why ssh is failing with **userB1**.

Last part of verbose message for 2 different users are as follows:

For userB1: ssh userB1@hostB <- failed

```
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA1/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/userA1/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/userA1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/userA1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/userA1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

For userB2: ssh userB2@hostB <- pass

```
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA1/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/userA1/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/userA1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 ................
..........
```

In hostB /var/log/secure file, when login using userB2 it shows:

```
Feb  3 11:54:19 development sshd[3246]: Accepted publickey for userB2 from hostA port 58773 ssh2
```

for userB1, it shows:

```
Feb  3 11:56:34 development sshd[3349]: Connection closed by hostA
```

In sshd_config file at hostB, there is nothing specified about any of those users.
Can any of you help me to figure out the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seem to be all right. 
One possible reason could be [Selinux context bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/965663) as mentioned in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication). In that case you have to run this command in your hostB from userB1:

```
restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh
```